# Write the URL in a variable in the Django view

Tags: python, html, django, folium

I want to put a link inside a variable (in View Django)
But I get a error.
In the slug section `(slug =% slug)`, Python confuses `% url` with `%u`!

> Error: %u format: a number is required, not str

I use the Folium library and want to put a link in the popup. So, I can not use the normal mode and  I have to use another method.

```
for i in range(10):
    slug=i
    url = Template(
    """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>
                    <a href="{% url 'test' slug= %slug %}" target="_blank" style=" text-align: 
   right; ">Mor Info</a>
                </body>
                </html>
    """%slug).render(Context({}))



popup = folium.features.GeoJsonPopup(
            fields=["name"],
            aliases=[f'{url}'],
            labels=True,
            localize=True,
            style="background-color: yellow;")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already pass a empty context, use that instead of string formatting.

```py
for i in range(10):
    slug=i
    url = Template(
    """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>
                    <a href="{% url 'test' slug=slug %}" target="_blank" style=" text-align: 
   right; ">Mor Info</a>
                </body>
                </html>
    """).render(Context({'slug': slug}))


   popup = folium.features.GeoJsonPopup(
            fields=["name"],
            aliases=[f'{url}'],
            labels=True,
            localize=True,
            style="background-color: yellow;")
```

Or just write `%s`, instead of `%slug`, you're mixing things up I think.

```py
print("%s" % "1")
print("%(bla)s" % {'bla':1})  # close to what you're attempting.
foo=1
print("{bla}".format(bla=1))
print(f"{foo}")
```

All print '1'.